# How to get a Workspace's working sets information in a plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, working-set

I want to get the runtime working sets information of the current workspace. I have tried the method:  IWorkingSet[]    getWorkingSets() of the IWorkbenchPage

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
      if (page != null) { IWorkingSet[] sets = page.getWorkingSets();}
```

but when I debug the code, the method returns nothing.

I am wondering am I use the right method to get a workspace's working sets information? If not, how to get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IWorkbenchPage` `getWorkingSets()` method returns the 'Window Working Sets' in use for the page - this option is not enabled by default so returns null.

If you want all the working sets defined in the workbench you use:

```java
IWorkingSetManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();

IWorkingSet [] allSets = manager.getAllWorkingSets();
```

The working set manager has many other methods for handling working sets.

Comment: Hi Greg, I have tried your method. It returns the exact data that I want. Thanks very much :)